# How do I get the kestrel web server to listen to non-localhost requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, kestrel-http-server

I've deployed my c#, asp.net 5, mvc 6 app to a windows 2008 server.  I've fired up `dnx web` and it is listening to port 5000 and works fine when accessing from local computer.

How do I get it to listen to non-localhost requests?

P.S.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975949/asp-net-5-kestrel-connect-within-lan) is not a duplicate of this...it refers to asp.net pre RC1 when hosting.ini actually had an .ini format.  Now, it's JSON and I can't find any documentation on what should actually be in it.

P.P.S.  The real solution is in the non-accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092934/9382) to the linked question, with a massive caveat.  Steps:

1. Change your project.json per the linked answer.
2. Publish your project to your server.
3. On the server, go to ...\approot\src\YourProject folder and open a command window there.
4. Run `dnx web` - it will fail
5. Run `dnu restore`
6. Run 'dnu build`
7. Run 'dnx web` - the web server should now start fine

## P.S.  For people upvoting this question.  It's outdated.  Very badly outdated!

It applied to the early versions of the .NET Core.  The question and the answers certainly aren't applicable for the current versions of the framework (e.g. 2.x, 3.x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET 5 Kestrel connect within LAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975949/asp-net-5-kestrel-connect-within-lan)

Comment: Well the second answer in the linked question refers to the JSON format. It's not useful for you either?

Comment: @chuex I tried that, and initially it crashed the web server on startup.  Not sure why.  Then I did `dnu restore`, followed by `dnu build` and then `dnx web` properly started the web server.  I don't know why its happening, but at least I am able to make it work.  There is definitely a bug that needs to be addressed before the final release. For now, this is the workaround.

Comment: I edited by question to reflect the solution.

Comment: @AngryHacker: You can specify `server.urls` parameter in application configuration file or command line parameters. The value can have multiple semicolon separated values see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel/KestrelServerInformation.cs#L65). The file name of configuration can be [hosting.json](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting/WebApplication.cs#L14), but it can be not only json: see [the issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/269). `--config` can be used to specify the config file name

Comment: I know this question had already been answered and marked as solved, but still I found a great post by Rick Strahl on his web log called [External Network Access to Kestrel and IIS Express in ASP.NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/28/External-Network-Access-to-Kestrel-and-IIS-Express-in-ASPNET-Core) so I wanted to share it with everyone who encounter this issue.

Comment: I guess we're supposed to downvote this question if we're using a modern version of .Net? Kind of confusing.

Comment: I read the big letters on being outdated but I absolutely needed the replies here even for a web API in .NET Core 3.1. I had first tried to bind to 0.0.0.0:5000 but IPv6 apparently happens around here and so this didn't work. Meanwhile [::]:5000 didn't work either for external IPv4 access. I had no idea binding to *:5000 was even a thing as we're now venturing out of the IPv4/IPv6 standard. So very helpful!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The default configuration file used by Kestrel server is `hosting.json`. The name was changed multiple times in different beta versions. If you use now `project.json` with the following `"command"` section

```json
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
}
```

then during starting the server from the command line by

```
dnx web
```

the file `hosting.json` will be read. The file

```json
{
    "server.urls": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
}
```

will configure the server to listen 5000 on every IP4 address. The configuration

```json
{
    "server.urls": "http://::5000;http://0.0.0.0:5000"
}
```

will inform to listen 5000 on both IP4 and IP6 address.

One can specify alternative configuration files by usage `ASPNET_ENV` environment variable or by the usage of `--config myconfig1.json` (or `config=myconfig1.json`). For example you can use

```
SET ASPNET_ENV=Development
```

and to create `hosting.Development.json` file with specific configuration. Alternatively you can use `project.json` with

```json
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
    "webProd": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config prod.json"
}
```

and start the server by usage

```cmd
dnx webProd
```

I have to remind additionally that it could be required that you allow to additionally listen and to register (to start `dnx web`). It's required because of the firewall and the local security of listening new TCP/HTTP ports. Something like below should make local registering and listening of 5000 port for everybody (IPv4 and IPv6):

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=0.0.0.0:5000
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=::5000
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:5000/ user=\Everyone
```

To be more secure you can adjust the above configuration to grant minimal rights.

**UPDATED:** Thanks @BlaneBunderson. One can use * instead of IP address (like `http://*:5000`) to listen on **any** IP4 and IP6 addresses from any interface. One should be carefully and not use these

- `http://*:5000;http://::5000`
- `http://::5000;http://*:5000`
- `http://*:5000;http://0.0.0.0:5000`
- `http://*:5000;http://0.0.0.0:5000`

because it will require to register IP6 address `::` or IP4 address `0.0.0.0` *twice*.

Corresponds to [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/80)

> Technically, any hostname that isn't "localhost" or a valid IPv4 or
>   IPv6 address will cause Kestrel to bind to all network interfaces.

I think that the behavior could be changed in the future. Thus I would recommend to use only `*:5000`, `0.0.0.0:5000` and `::5000` form for registering of any IT address.

**UPDATED 2:** ASP.NET Core RC2 changes (see [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/174)) the behavior of loading the defaults. One have to make changes in the `Main` to load the settings from `hosting.json` and the command line parameters. Below is an example of the usage

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseUrls("http://*:1000", "https://*:1234", "http://0.0.0.0:5000")
        .UseEnvironment("Development")
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

The above code use three bindings: `"http://*:1000"`, `"https://*:1234"`, `"http://0.0.0.0:5000"` by default instead of usage the default port 5000 by default (to be exact the usage of `http://localhost:5000`). The call of `.UseConfiguration(config)` are made *after* `.UseUrls`. Thus the configuration loaded from `hosting.json` or the command line overwrite the default options. If one remove `.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` line then the `hosting.json` will be loaded from the same directory where the application dll will be compiled (for example `bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0`).

One can use execution like

```
dotnet.exe run --server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

to overwrite the default settings (from `UseUrls`) and the settings from `"server.urls"` property of `hosting.json` if it's exist.

In the same way one could overwrite the ULR settings by setting the environment variable

```
set ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS=http://localhost:12541/
```

then the default start of the application using `dotnet.exe run` will use `http://localhost:12541/` for binding.

You can find [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/SocialSample/Program.cs) an example of the usage of HTTPS binding.

**REMARK:** The name of environment variable is changed from `ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS` to `ASPNETCORE_URLS` in later versions of ASP.NET(see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration) the documentation of ASP.NET Core 3.1).

Comment: In addition you can use "server.urls": "http://*:5000" instead of "server.urls": "http://0.0.0.0:5000" (Personally I think the * makes a little more sense.)

Comment: @BlaneBunderson: Thank for your suggestion! I have to add that  `http://*:5000` is the same as `http://::5000;http://0.0.0.0:5000` and not `http://0.0.0.0:5000`. It force listening for both IPv4 and IPv6. You can verify it by usage `http://*:5000;http://::5000` or `http://::5000;http://*:5000`. One get the error "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvException: Error -4091 EADDRINUSE address already in use" during registering the second address. In some scenarios registering of both IPv4 and IPv6 is good, in another scenarios it's not good. In any way it's good to mention the way.

Comment: Excellent update for RC2, thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: wouldn't `.UseStartup<Startup>()` override `.UseConfiguration(config)` in your "update 2" example?

Comment: there is a typo in that environment variable, it should be ASPNETCORE_URLS

Comment: @nrjohnstone: To be exactly: it's not a typo. The answer is written **before** ASP.NET Core 1.0 was released. The name of environment variable is changed during the versions. It was `ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS` initially and it was changed later (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/WebHostBuilder.cs#L159-L162) the code fragment of ASP.NET Core 2.2). Now (in version ASP.NET Core 3.1) it's `ASPNETCORE_URLS` (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration)).

Comment: this worked for me - > set ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000/

Comment: What does the + in URLS mean?

Answer (score 33):

In RC2 the commands section of project.json is no longer used. I haven't gotten Kestrel to pick up the hosting.json yet, but you can programatically set the port in the Main of the application where the new WebHostBuilder is created and configured. Just add .UseUrls() method like in the sample below

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000/")
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

Comment: This was a big help. I used `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")` instead, and port forwarded 5000 with empty Host IP on VirtualBox, and finally I can get to the Docker-hosted .NET Core endpoints from my Mac. Sweet!

Comment: For info on using hosting.json in RC2 and more detailed explanation, read Oleg's answer above, especially "Updated 2"

Comment: Also applicable to 1.0.0-preview2-003121, docker image

Answer (score 26):

If you use asp.net core 2.1+,modify config section in appsettings.json.

```
"Kestrel": {
  "EndPoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5002"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: This one has also consistently worked for me when running from either VS Code or Visual Studio for Mac.

`ASPNETCORE_URLS` did not work for me

Comment: I get `Cant be reached` when opening on localhost with this url

Comment: It also works in .NET 6.

Answer (score 24):

For **AspNetCore 3.1+** just add the following line in the file `appsettings.json`:

```
"Urls": "http://*:80"
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I cannot find why solutions with `hosting.json` won't work tho.

Comment: Thanks man, spent an hour trying to connect from Parallels VM to my aspnet core app running on the host macbook

Comment: If you're doing this through the Visual Studio GUI (Project properties -> Debug), you need to use `http://0.0.0.0:80`, not `*`.

Comment: Brilliant! This solution worked for me in the latest .Net 6 too. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

If you are trying to put an ASP.NET Core application inside a docker container (which was my use case for needing to listen to non-localhost addresses), note that this use case has already been put together for you by Microsoft.  You can see the full glory at https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore/

At current (v1.0.1) the key magic for solving this problem is that the source Dockerfile contains a url environment variable setting, and the application does not attempt to override this.  (Indeed, a containerized application should internally assert as little as possible about the environment where it will run.)

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:80
```

Note the plus sign rather than asterisk there.  I actually recommend visiting the above dockerhub link over reading my answer for as long as the link is good.  Version 1.1 is just around the corner, and things may change again in the future.

When running the container, make sure to expose guest port 80, per the environment variable setting.  For example:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:80 myapp
curl localhost:8000
```

Comment: this was my use case as well and the link were extremely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to modify `launchSettings.json`. Replace `"applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000",` with `"applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000",`. Like so:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:3031"
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/`.

If running from Visual Studio, you add the environment variable from the Debug tab of the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

It is added to services as such:

```
services.AddSingleton<IServer, KestrelServerImpl>();
```

Unconventional means but see below:

Extensions:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using System.Net;

namespace Utils
{
    public static class KestrelExtensions
    {
        private static IManagedLockObject lockObject;
        private static Queue<KestrelOptionsInfo> optionsQueue;
        private static List<KestrelOptionsInfo> listeners;
        private static Thread dispatchThread;
        private static ManualResetEvent stopListeningResetEvent;
        private static CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        public static void UsePorts(this IWebHostBuilder hostBuilder, params int[] ports)
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
            var location = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
            var launchSettingsFile = Path.Combine(location, @"Properties\launchsettings.json");

            if (File.Exists(launchSettingsFile))
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(launchSettingsFile))
                {
                    var settings = JsonExtensions.ReadJson<LaunchSettings>(reader);
                    var launchSettingUrl = settings.profiles.https.applicationUrl;
                    var uri = new Uri(launchSettingUrl);

                    hostBuilder.UseKestrel((o) => HandleKestrelOptions(o, uri.Port, ports));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                hostBuilder.UseKestrel((o) => HandleKestrelOptions(o, -1, ports));
            }
        }

        private static void HandleKestrelOptions(KestrelServerOptions options, int launchSettingsPort, int[] ports)
        {
            var oneTimeTimer = new OneTimeTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            serviceProvider = options.ApplicationServices;

            oneTimeTimer.Start(() =>
            {
                foreach (var port in ports)
                {
                    if (launchSettingsPort != -1 && launchSettingsPort == port)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Cannot pass port that is equal to launchsettings port. Kestrel handles these automatically");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine($"Instruction to listen on local host, port {port}");

                    if (optionsQueue == null)
                    {
                        lockObject = LockManager.CreateObject();
                        stopListeningResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                        optionsQueue = new Queue<KestrelOptionsInfo>();
                        listeners = new List<KestrelOptionsInfo>();

                        dispatchThread = new Thread(DispatchThreadProc);

                        dispatchThread.IsBackground  = true;
                        dispatchThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                        dispatchThread.Name = "Kestrel dispatch thread";

                        dispatchThread.Start();
                    }

                    using (lockObject.Lock())
                    {
                        optionsQueue.Enqueue(new KestrelOptionsInfo(options, port));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private static void DispatchThreadProc()
        {
            KestrelOptionsInfo kestrelOptionsInfo = null;

            using (lockObject.Lock())
            {
                if (optionsQueue.Count > 0)
                {
                    kestrelOptionsInfo = optionsQueue.Dequeue();
                    listeners.Add(kestrelOptionsInfo);
                }
            }

            if (kestrelOptionsInfo != null)
            {
                var options = kestrelOptionsInfo.Options;
                var port = kestrelOptionsInfo.Port;
                var listenThread = new Thread(() => ListenThreadProc(kestrelOptionsInfo));

                listenThread.IsBackground  = true;
                listenThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
                listenThread.Name = $"Kestrel listen thread for port {port}";
                
                kestrelOptionsInfo.ListenThread = listenThread;

                listenThread.Start();
            }
        }

        private static void ListenThreadProc(KestrelOptionsInfo kestrelOptionsInfo)
        {
            var options = kestrelOptionsInfo.Options;
            var port = kestrelOptionsInfo.Port;
            var thread = kestrelOptionsInfo.ListenThread;
            var server = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IServer));
            var addressBindContext = server.GetPrivatePropertyValue<object>("AddressBindContext");
            var createBinding = addressBindContext.GetPropertyValue<Func<ListenOptions, CancellationToken, Task>>("CreateBinding");
            var ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
            var listenOptions = TypeExtensions.ActivatePrivate<ListenOptions>(ipEndpoint);

            listenOptions.SetPropertyValue(nameof(listenOptions.KestrelServerOptions), kestrelOptionsInfo.Options);

            Console.WriteLine($"Attempting listen on {port}");

            HandleListenOptions(listenOptions);

            kestrelOptionsInfo.BindingTask = createBinding(listenOptions, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

            while (!stopListeningResetEvent.WaitOne(100))
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Stopping listen on {port}");
        }

        private static void HandleListenOptions(ListenOptions listenOptions)
        {
            listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http1AndHttp2;
            listenOptions.UseHttps();
            listenOptions.UseConnectionHandler<UtilsConnectionHandler>();
        }
    }

    public class EnvironmentVariables
    {
        public string ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT { get; set; }
    }

    public class Http
    {
        public string commandName { get; set; }
        public bool dotnetRunMessages { get; set; }
        public bool launchBrowser { get; set; }
        public string launchUrl { get; set; }
        public string applicationUrl { get; set; }
        public EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables { get; set; }
    }

    public class Https
    {
        public string commandName { get; set; }
        public bool dotnetRunMessages { get; set; }
        public bool launchBrowser { get; set; }
        public string launchUrl { get; set; }
        public string applicationUrl { get; set; }
        public EnvironmentVariables environmentVariables { get; set; }
    }

    public class Profiles
    {
        public Http http { get; set; }
        public Https https { get; set; }
    }

    public class LaunchSettings
    {
        [JsonProperty("$schema")]
        public string schema { get; set; }
        public Profiles profiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```