# Setting a Port in both project.json and launchSettings.json

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express, kestrel-http-server

I want my project to start on a particular port using both IIS Express and Kestrel in Visual Studio, using the 'IIS Express' or 'web' start button.

By default, the launchSettings.json file contains a specific port number for IIS Express. However, Kestrel is always started on the default port 5000. How can I get Kestrel to also start on the same port as IIS Express?

## launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5020/",
      "sslPort": 44320
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## project.json Extract

```
{
    ...
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
    },
    ...
}
```

I have tried changing the web command in project.json to:

```
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel  --server.urls http://localhost:5020"
```

However, this completely stops the site starting in IIS Express.

Comment: Try to use `hosting.json`. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/315935).

Comment: I'm doing something very similar to what you tried [here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/example.WebApp/project.json) and [here](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/example.WebApp/Properties/launchSettings.json) and it works for me. iis uses port 60000 and my custom port-tenants command launches 2 instances on different ports but one of them is the same 60000 as IIS. But both cannot run at once I have to kill IIS express to use the command or kill the command to use IIS. I remember issues at first but reboot fixed it.

Comment: This will work better in RC2. In RC1 IIS would provide a dynamic address _in addition to_ kestrel's configured address. In RC2 IIS will _replace_ kestrel's configured address and avoid conflicts.