# How to run ASP.NET Core site under IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I've studied the [docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html) on how to do this but am still not understanding:
I've published my site from Visual Studio and can run the site from the command prompt using the command:

```
dotnet MyDotnetCoreApp.dll
```

That tells me the app started on http://localhost:5000  and I can browse to it just fine.

But how do I get IIS to start the app though so that I can go to the normal port 80?  The web.config has the correct entry:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyDotnetCoreApp.dll" .... />
```

All I get is 500 An error occurred while starting the application.

Must be missing some simple step. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You web.config must point to the correct file path of the ASP.NET Core module. Use Google to locate the correct path you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in your case you are not running using IIS, but using [Kestrel HTTP Server](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer).
You can read about Kestrel hosting configuration (and find how to change listening port) in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/2833802).

In case if you need to run under IIS (that is still publish option #1 on Windows, despite IIS is acting now merely as a reverse proxy and the application itself runs as a separate process using the Kestrel HTTP server), you may find [Running ASP.Net Core applications with IIS](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/) article very useful, as it explains not just how to make ASP.NET Core works with IIS, but also *"what’s really happening, why it’s happening and how the blocks fit together"*

Comment: Thanks - this last link was quite useful and I now have it working on localhost.  Now to see if I can get it on IIS production server....