# Json configuration source ignored in Kestrel setup

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm working with an ASP.NET Core 1 RTM web app and I'm updating Kestrel setup to latest conventions. Setup aims at having the following sources for `server.urls`, from lowest to highest priority:

1. URLs set in `Program.Main()` code (default, e.g. for production)
2. URLs set in `hosting.Development.json` (e.g. to override default while developing)
3. URLs set in environment variables (e.g. to override default for staging or other production env.)

As per latest references (e.g. [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/540776) and [here on Github](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/737)), this is what I got now:

`ProjDir\Program.cs`:

```c#
public class Program
{
    // Entry point for the application
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string hostingDevFilepath = "hosting.Development.json";
        const string environmentVariablesPrefix = "ASPNETCORE_";

        string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var hostingConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(currentPath)
            .AddJsonFile(hostingDevFilepath, optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(environmentVariablesPrefix)
            .Build();

        System.Console.WriteLine("From hostingConfig: " +
            hostingConfig.GetSection("server.urls").Value);

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseUrls("https://0.0.0.0")
            .UseConfiguration(hostingConfig)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(currentPath)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

`ProjDir\hosting.Development.json`:

```json
{
    "server.urls": "http://localhost:51254"
}
```

From command line, having set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`, this is the output:

```
> dotnet run

Project Root (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) was previously compiled. Skipping compilation.
From hostingConfig: http://localhost:51254
info: AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.OpenIdConnectServerMiddleware[0]
      An existing key was automatically added to the signing credentials list: <<yadda yadda yadda>>
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: <<my project root dir>>
Now listening on: https://0.0.0.0:443
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

My expected output would be instead `Now listening on: http://localhost:51254`.
URLs value is correctly picked up from JSON source (as per console log), but then Kestrel configuration ignores that, even if `UseConfiguration` comes **after** `UseUrls`.

What am I missing? Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What if you use `urls` as a name instead of `server.urls`? (https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/e7b8c3f90a781a55658b4245571c5bf5dac5e56e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/WebHostDefaults.cs#L15)

Comment: I just tried (re)adding both a `UseUrls()` and then set `urls` in Json sources. The settings from Json source is picked up correctly! Two questions? Q1: is this documented somewhere yet (apart from looking at the code :) ) Q2: how come that if there's no `UseUrls` then even `server.urls` works? Tnx

Comment: I believe it is being picked up automatically if it is configured. `UseUrls` allows you to configure urls programmatically.

Comment: Yep, that I got it. It's this *new* setting name that I was not aware of. And it sounds strange UseUrls works with the new one and not with the old. But then again this just came out of RC ... Please feel free to reply this question.

Comment: I think it was changed post RC1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `urls` instead of `server.urls`. The name of the setting changed post RC2.

Comment: The referenced change belongs to a commit tagged with 1.0.0, so probably was even post RC2, landing to RTM

Answer (score 1):

Did some more tests. It seems to me that as soon as `UseUrls()` is present, no matter in which order, all Json config sources are ignored.

So I tried to come up with a solution supporting more than one `hosting.json` file, e.g. a default one and then one per environment. Basically I tried to replicate in `Program.Main()` a behavior similar to `Startup.Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)`, where one can use both `"appsettings.json"` and `$"appsettings.{hostingEnv.EnvironmentName}.json"` as source. The only issue is that in *Program.Main()* there's no *IHostingEnvironment* available, but [this GH issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/761) reminded me that we still have `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("some-variable")` in our toolbelt.

Here's the full solution, please feel free to suggest improvements or (even better) some semplification:

```c#
public class Program
{
    // Entry point for the application
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string environmentVariablesPrefix = "ASPNETCORE_";

        string hostingEnvironmentKey = $"{environmentVariablesPrefix}ENVIRONMENT";
        string hostingEnvironmentValue;

        try
        {
            hostingEnvironmentValue = Environment
                .GetEnvironmentVariable(hostingEnvironmentKey);
        }
        catch
        {
            hostingEnvironmentValue = "Development";
        }

        const string hostingFilepath = "hosting.json";
        string envHostingFilepath = $"hosting.{hostingEnvironmentValue}.json";

        string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        var hostingConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(currentPath)
            .AddJsonFile(hostingFilepath, optional: true)
            .AddJsonFile(envHostingFilepath, optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(environmentVariablesPrefix)
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(hostingConfig)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(currentPath)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

```js
// in hosting.json
{
  "server.urls": "https://0.0.0.0"
}

// in hosting.Development.json
{
  "server.urls": "http://localhost:51254"
}
```