# Cannot change Kestrel listening port from command line

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have the following entry point:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

It works if I add hosting.json file like

```
{
  "server.urls": "http://0.0.0.0:5001"
}
```

or if I define environment variable (have found name [here](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639))

```
SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://0.0.0.0:5001
```

But if I pass `--server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5001` as parameter, the app listening the default 5000 port:

```
> dotnet run --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5001
...
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

Comment: What exact version of dotnet are you using?

Comment: @DirkVollmar dotnet --version returns 1.0.0-preview2-003121

Comment: Please try updating to the latest version then (if Oleg's answer did not already resolve your problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
dotnet run --server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5001
```

instead of

```
dotnet run --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5001
```

See [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/315935) for more details.

Comment: still listening on default port

Comment: @Set are you sure you passed `--server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5002`? In your updated question you use `--server.url` (with out the `s`).

Comment: The correct configuration settings is now just "urls". So change your hosting.json to {
  "urls": "http://0.0.0.0:5001"
}

Comment: @cbp: The question was about "change Kestrel listening port from **command line**". The information about `hosting.json` is described in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/315935) for example, which I referenced too.