# How to configure IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions.Authority to use wildcards

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I successfully setup IdentityServer4 with ASP.NET Core.

As a default config I had this:

```
IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions options = new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:5000",                
    ScopeName = "scope",
    ScopeSecret = "ScopeSecret",
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,                
};
```

Now, using this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212765/how-do-i-get-the-kestrel-web-server-to-listen-to-non-localhost-requests) I configured to be read from configuration files and so they can be any numbers in production.

For example if I setup API to be running at `http://*:5000` then the client can connect to it via the service IP address like `http://192.168.1.100:5000`.

Once the client obtains the Bearer token and tries to use it, an `Internal Server Error` occures with this exception:

```
Unable to obtain configuration from: 
'http://*:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'. 
---> System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://*:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'. 
---> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

What is the correct way to configure IdS4 to have dynamic authority?

**Update**

It seems the problem is with Issuer, any idea on this?

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: 

IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'http://192.168.1.100:5000'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'http://localhost:5000' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'null'.

   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateIssuer(String issuer, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
```

Answer (score 6):

By a big surprise, all I needed, was to set a value (almost any value) for `IssuerUri`:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ////...

    var identiyBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireSsl = false;
        options.IssuerUri = "MyCompany";      
    });

    ////...
}
```

Now, by the above config, I can use the service by any IP address.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find I could just put in `MyCompany`

But in my log files I had the following:

```
  Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'https://crm.example.com'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: 'MyCompany' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: 'null'.
```

I don't quite know what 'issuer' means but I was able to just take 'https://crm.example.com' and get things working with this :

```
 options.IssuerUri = "https://crm.example.com";
```