# Why Startup's IConfigurationRoot is null?

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to pass command line arguments to `Startup` class. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212765/how-do-i-get-the-kestrel-web-server-to-listen-to-non-localhost-requests/34221690#34221690) example, I modified my `Program` class and it looks like this:

```
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("generalsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
            .AddCommandLine(args);  
        var config = builder.Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

`generalsettings.json` contains following data:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore I commented out default `Startup` class' constructor. Then I noticed that that's where `IConfigurationRoot Configuration` is assigned, and therefore, when I'm trying to use it from `ConfigureServices` it's null. I'm trying to use (I think) configuration built in `Program`'s `Main`. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**

To make it clear: I'm trying to use `args` in `Startup` class.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here. I feel like what I think you are trying to do could be accomplished using your launchSettings.json. Which should be in your Properties for the project.

Comment: I'm trying to use `args` in `Startup` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there has been a fair amount of discussion about this sort of thing in [GitHub Aspnet hosting repo issues area](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues). The GitHub repositories are always a good place to look on an interesting problem like this one.

To sum things up for you, do not set up IConfigurationRoot in Program.Main, set it up in Startup. You can pass the command line arguments to the Startup constructor from Program.cs like so:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .ConfigureServices(services => services
                .AddSingleton(new ConsoleArgs(args))
            )
            .Build();
        host.Run();
    }
```

where ConsoleArgs is a holder class you can create yourself that looks like:

```
public class ConsoleArgs
{
    public ConsoleArgs(string[] args)
    {
        Args = args;
    }
    public string[] Args { get; }
}
```

Obviously, configuring a ConsoleArgs *service* is the key. This will allow it to be injected into the Startup constructor. Then your Startup class constructor looks something like

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ConsoleArgs args)
{
     var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("generalsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
    .AddCommandLine(args.Args);  
    var config = builder.Build();
}
```

The pattern here is "configure you hosting environment Program, configure you application in Startup"

Comment: that passed `args` correctly, but on `Configuration = builder.Build();` exception was thrown, saying that `Unrecognized argument format: 'asdf'.` ("asdf" being argument that I passed for testing).

Comment: however, when I changed argument to asdf=eee, it compiled okay. is that because arguments should be in dictionary (key-value) format?

Comment: yeah, there are some assumptions made in the naming of configuration keys. Since key/value defined in JSON get overridden when you add an environmental variable or a command line item, and since all this stuff has to run on multiple platforms, the names of things have some restrictions. JSON is a tree structure because it represents and object, but command line args and environmental variables are obviously just key simple value. So there is a bit of magic to define an env var that overloads a JSON subobject value. See https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration for details. :-)