# Unable to connect to custom port on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm unable to connect to my Ubuntu EC2 instance on port 5000 where my app is running.

1. I have security group rule in place to allow 80 and 5000
2. Ubuntu firewall is disabled -sudo ufw disable and I tried enabling it and added port 5000 as well
3. I'm able to ping the server
4. But accessing port 5000 does not work

Comment: did you try `curl localhost:5000` inside machine? is it accessible on localhost?

Comment: Yes. I did. It is accessible.

Comment: which server you are running? is it bind to localhost? is nodejs based application or which framework?

Comment: It is .net core api running on localhost on EC2.

Comment: did you set `.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000/")`?

Comment: No. I didn't. I'll give it a try. Thank you very much !

Comment: I added this line  .UseUrls("https://*:5001/"); Still not able to access from outside. port 5001 is allowed in the security config.

Comment: It should be `UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5001/")`

Comment: Sorry. The changes I made was not updated on EC2 properly.    .UseUrls(new string[]{"http://*:5000/","https://*:5001/"});  with this change, Im able access it via http://serverip/5000 But still 5001 not working. may be a security certificate issue.

Comment: Sure. Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If working on localhost, and SG also allow the traffic then it Seems like your server is bind with localhost, update to server configuration to listen `0.0.0.0`.

Add this in the configuration.

```
UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5001/")
```

[How do I get the kestrel web server to listen to non-localhost requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212765/how-do-i-get-the-kestrel-web-server-to-listen-to-non-localhost-requests)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using port `5001` instead of port `5000`?

Comment: nope, it was just an example, the port should be same as the one on which server listening