# How can I host a Asp.Net Core Website on my Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-hosting, raspberry-pi4

I try to host my Asp.Net Core webpage on my Raspberry Pi 4 but the Website can't reach it. I disabled the firewall etc already and I've tried a few tutorials but it hasn't really helped me. I can host the default Asp.Net Page but I can't reach my Application. Can someone help me please?
That's what my terminal looks like:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\Aydin\Desktop\PlaudertischSoftware\PlaudertischSoftware
```

Comment: From where are you trying to open your Asp.Net Core website? From the Pi or from another device on your network?

Comment: If you're binding the website to localhost, it might only listen to local connections. Try changing it to 0.0.0.0 as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212765/how-do-i-get-the-kestrel-web-server-to-listen-to-non-localhost-requests

Comment: I try to host it from my pi. And yes I am binding it to a localhost

Comment: I've tried to make it like in the Stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212765/how-do-i-get-the-kestrel-web-server-to-listen-to-non-localhost-requests but it still just listens to local connections