# ASP.NET Core 6 debug using device name not just local host

Tags: asp.net-core-6.0

I have created a basic WebAPI with ASP.NET Core 6 and Visual Studio.
I just get a main route that returns "Hello world", and modified port to use 8888
When I debug this, I can get my expected string if I use `localhost:8888` however I'd like to make it work to when I run `device:8888` (device been my machine's name).
Seems I am using a Kestrel server. I've tried a few things, but were not working for me:

[How do I get the kestrel web server to listen to non-localhost requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212765/how-do-i-get-the-kestrel-web-server-to-listen-to-non-localhost-requests)

[How to specify the port an ASP.NET Core application is hosted on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on/55276201#55276201)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Any ideas on how can I call http://device:8888 with my debug server running?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I changed the `launchsetting.json` to change the `applicationUrl` as a custom name. Then I run the API project and get the error below. It indicates a DNS error.
[image]

So I modify the host file to add `127.0.0.1 mycustomname` and this time it worked for me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is this what you want?

Comment: thank you @Tiny Wang - I don't think I need to modify my hosts to achieve that. I think I found the way of doing it - reading and understanding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: thank you for your answer, Mr. Tiny Wang! :)

Answer (score 1):

I used the following:
[Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https/28586593#28586593)  - to stop automatically converting localhost into https
and then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0 - a few ways of doing this:

- using dot net run --urls=http://*:8888 (defines any device and port 8888)
- using config, adding the following in `appsettings.json`

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
      }
    }
  }
```

The doc also defines the use of `ASPNETCORE_URLS` but I was not able to make it work.