# how to resolve exception with `dnx web`

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

I've created a new asp.net web project in visual studio 2015. I've installed asp.net 5 rc1-update1 and the relevant dnx runtimes. The project runs fine through visual studio but whenever I try to run from the command line I run into 2 problems:

1. The package manager console is pointed at the solution folder and
   not the .src\WebApplication folder. Is this an indication that
   there's an issue with my visual studio tooling?
2. When I cd into the web application folder and execute `dnx web` it
   throws an exception
   `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvException: Error -4092
   EACCES permission denied`

Is this indicative of a bad configuration or install? Is there an alternative to uninstalling everything and reinstalling?

project.json is straight out of File->New Project as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp min" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your project.json file, as well as your project structure?

Comment: did you try to run that command in an console with admin privileges? (run as administrator)

Comment: I did try running as administrator and the problem persists.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem to your second issue which was fixed by amending my "web" command to...

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5000"
  }
```

See [here](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34092934/253131) for some further information.