# How to specify the port an ASP.NET Core application is hosted on?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

When using `WebHostBuilder` in a `Main` entry-point, how can I specify the port it binds to?

By default it uses 5000.

Note that this question is specific to the new ASP.NET Core API (currently in 1.0.0-RC2).

Comment: examine `launchSettings.json` from `Properties` folder. You can change the port in the `launchUrl`.

Comment: @Oleg, I had some IIS related settings in there left over from RC1's project template. They didn't have any effect.

Comment: One can use `hosting.json` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/315935)), which were used by default in RC1 and one need just add `.AddJsonFile("hosting.json", optional: true)` (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/174))

Comment: Using the configuration stack seems indeed much better than relying on a purely VS-specific mechanism (launchSettings.json).

Comment: @DrewNoakes: I appended [my old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/315935) with **UPDATED 2** part. It describes some variation of changing the default port and usage of `hosting.json` or the command line for configuring of the binding.

Answer (score 623, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 3.1, there are four main ways to specify a custom port:

- Using command line arguments, by starting your .NET application with `--urls=[url]`:

  ```
  dotnet run --urls=http://localhost:5001/
  ```
- Using `appsettings.json`, by adding a `Urls` node:

  ```json
  {
     "Urls": "http://localhost:5001"
  }
  ```
- Using environment variables, with `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5001/`.
- Using `UseUrls()`, if you prefer doing it programmatically:

  ```cs
  public static class Program
  {
       public static void Main(string[] args) =>
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(builder =>
               {
                   builder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                   builder.UseUrls("http://localhost:5001/");
               });
  }
  ```

Or, if you're still using the web host builder instead of the generic host builder:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) =>
        new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5001/")
            .Build()
            .Run();
}
```

Comment: The usage of fixed URLs directly in the code is not the best choice in my opinion.

Comment: Tested this and it works well, thanks. @Oleg, could you flesh out an answer showing what config you need? It might be good to have this in a config file.

Comment: @Oleg maybe, but using `UseUrls` is the approach recommended by the ASP.NET team for self-hosting scenarios (the value itself doesn't have to be hardcoded, obviously). That said, I updated my answer to mention how you could do that using the configuration builder.

Comment: @Pinpoint: I posted [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/315935), where one can find how to change the port using `hosting.json`. The only thing, which one have to do is forcing reading the information in RC2 (see [the announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/174)).

Comment: @Oleg I guess it would be worth updating your answer to add a tiny snippet showing what's needed to make it work with RC2 ;)

Comment: @Pinpoint: The problem exist not with ASP.NET Core only. It's difficult to go over all old answers and to update there after publishing of every new version. :-)

Comment: @Oleg agreed. Personally, I spent 1 hour yesterday to update all my ASP.NET Core security-related questions. I know how painful it can be :)

Comment: @Pinpoint: It's very good if you can to do this, but I posted more as 5000 answers. It would take to many time...

Comment: @Oleg luckily, all your answers are not about ASP.NET Core, so you won't have to update ~5000 posts :) And nothing prevents you from marking your answers as "community wiki posts" to let the community update your posts when needed. That said, I think we're now a bit off-topic :)

Comment: @Pinpoint: I appended [my old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34221690/315935) with **UPDATED 2** part.

Comment: You'll need the following package: `using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine;`

Comment: The post should be updated... dotnet run --urls=http://localhost:5001/ is what you need to use.

Comment: Hardcoding "localhost" either in `dotnet run` or in `UseUrls` is a bad idea because once this code makes it off the dev's machine any requests that don't contain localhost will get rejected.  This caused me much pain in Kubernetes.  Instead use the string like `http://*:5001`.

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Once it is in the code you need to recompile the code to change the urls. Keeping it in a configuration file or environment variable allows to use the same build in different environments. The bigger the application the more important this becomes due to possibly long build times.

Answer (score 148):

You can insert Kestrel section in asp.net core 2.1+ appsettings.json file.

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5002"
      }
    }
  },
```

if you **do not have** kestrel section, you can use "urls":

```
{
    "urls":"http://*.6001;https://*.6002"
}
```

but if you have kestrel in appsettings.json, urls section will failure.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed :-) Better than UseUrls(). More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: THIS actually works with binaries generated through `dotnet publish`.

Comment: Isn't this defining [the port Kestrel is binded to IIS (proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871318/determine-port-kestrel-binded-to) rather than the port the app is hosted on in IIS?

Comment: @user12345 In IIS hosting,Kestrel use dynamic port binding.

Comment: also works with netcore 3.0 running web api from exe, briliant!!!

Comment: This can also be set with an environment variable `export Kestrel__EndPoints__Http__Url=http://0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: This works, but Swagger doesn't launch anymore. :(

Answer (score 84):

Follow up answer to help anyone doing this with the VS docker integration. I needed to change to port 8080 to run using the "flexible" environment in google appengine.

You'll need the following in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:8080
EXPOSE 8080
```

and you'll need to modify the port in docker-compose.yml as well:

```
    ports:
      - "8080"
```

Comment: Thanks, we can set variables in windows command promt the same way:
set ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080

Comment: this isn't working for me. are you sure this is all that you modified? Did you need to do anything special to your image afterwords or anything with docker?

Comment: It's been so long that it may have changed, but if I recall that was all I needed to do.

Comment: in VS Code, you can add that "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://+:8080" on "env" section of launch.json, to override other settings.

Answer (score 45):

You can specify hosting URL without any changes to your app.

Create a `Properties/launchSettings.json` file in your project directory and fill it with something like this:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyApp1-Dev": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001/"
    }
  }
}
```

`dotnet run` command should pick your `launchSettings.json` file and will display it in the console:

```
C:\ProjectPath [master ≡]
λ  dotnet run
Using launch settings from C:\ProjectPath\Properties\launchSettings.json...
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: C:\ProjectPath
Now listening on: http://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments

Comment: Work in the appSettings.json too?

Comment: No, it has to be in `[ProjectRoot]/Properties/launchSettings.json`, but the beautiful thing is, it works without a hitch.

Comment: This is only useful during development, does not work with binaries. in order to use `dotnet run` you need access to the source code.

Answer (score 42):

Above .net core 2.2 the method Main support args with WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

You can build your project and go to `bin` run command like this

```
dotnet <yours>.dll --urls=http://0.0.0.0:5001
```

or with multi-urls

```
dotnet <yours>.dll --urls="http://0.0.0.0:5001;https://0.0.0.0:5002"
```

---

Edit 2021/09/14

After .net core 3.1 you can change the file `appsettings.json` in the project, Config section `Urls` and `Kestrel` all works. And you can use either. `Urls` will easier.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "MicrosoftHostingLifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Urls": "http://0.0.0.0:5002",
  //"Kestrel": {
  //  "EndPoints": {
  //    "Http": {
  //      "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5000"
  //    },
  //    "Https": {
  //      "Url": "https://0.0.0.0:5001"
  //    }
  //  }
  //},
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Use `http://0.0.0.0:5000` can access the webserver from remote connect, If you set to `http://localhost:5000` that will access only in your computer.

To make `Kestrel` setting works, you shoud change code in `Program.cs` in the project.

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
                 {
                     services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
                 });
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Comment: you can simple to use 'dotnet run --urls=http://0.0.0.0:5001' in project directory

Comment: This answer worked for me.  For the multi-url case, I had to change the comma `,` to a semi-colon like this: `--urls="http://localhost:5001;https://localhost:5002"`.  Otherwise, had an error starting Kestrel: `System.InvalidOperationException: A path base can only be configured using IApplicationBuilder.UsePathBase().`

Answer (score 35):

Alternative solution is to use a `hosting.json` in the root of the project.

```
{
  "urls": "http://localhost:60000"
}
```

And then in `Program.cs`

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("hosting.json", true)
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. server.urls is now urls and make sure you add entry to project.json "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot",
      "hosting.json"
    ]
 },

Comment: I updated his answer with the correct property `urls` - thanks @ManishJain

Answer (score 31):

If using `dotnet run`

```
dotnet run --urls="http://localhost:5001"
```

Comment: The perfect answer! Works in docker. Replaced only "localhost" with "0.0.0.0"

Answer (score 15):

When hosted in docker containers (linux version for me), you might get a 'Connection Refused' message. In that case you can use IP address **0.0.0.0** which means "all IP addresses on this machine" instead of the **localhost** loopback to fix the port forwarding.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000/")
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

On .Net Core 3.1 just follow Microsoft Doc that it is pretty simple: [kestrel-aspnetcore-3.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

To summarize:

1. Add the below ConfigureServices section to CreateDefaultBuilder on `Program.cs`:

   ```
   // using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
           {
               services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(
                   context.Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));
           })
           .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
           {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
           });
   ```
2. Add the below basic config to `appsettings.json` file (more config options on Microsoft article):

   ```
   "Kestrel": {
       "EndPoints": {
           "Http": {
               "Url": "http://0.0.0.0:5002"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Open CMD or Console on your project Publish/Debug/Release binaries folder and run:

   ```
   dotnet YourProject.dll
   ```
4. Enjoy exploring your site/api at your http://localhost:5002

Answer (score 6):

Go to properties/launchSettings.json and find your appname and under this, find applicationUrl. you will see, it is running localhost:5000, change it to whatever you want. and then run dotnet run...... hurrah

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can specify port by running app via command line.

Simply run command:

```
dotnet run --server.urls http://localhost:5001
```

*Note: Where 5001 is the port you want to run on.*

Answer (score 3):

I found this question relating to .Net Core 3.1 but try to do it with .Net 6. So the first two options still work, but the programatical way has changed. (And that was what I needed).

So with .Net 6 you can use command line arguments:

`dotnet run --urls=http://localhost:5001/`

Using appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Urls": "http://*:14071"
}
```

Programmatically you should now:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
//...
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:14071");
```

### Update

It is also possible to use ConfigureKestrel with server options to define the Port. What gives you the option to define more details for Kestrel Options.

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(14072);
});
```

or

```
var ipEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 14072);
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
serverOptions.Listen(ipEndpoint, listenOptions =>
{
    listenOptions.UseHttps("Your.pfx");
    listenOptions.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
       // Your Middleware for e.g. logging
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the port issue in Net core 3.1 by using the following

In the Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHost(x => x.UseUrls("https://localhost:4000", "http://localhost:4001"))
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
}
```

You can access the application using

```
http://localhost:4000

https://localhost:4001
```

Comment: This gets completely ignored.  Still listens on another port (no idea where that is specified(.