# ASP.NET Core 1.0 / Kestrel on Linux is not creating unix socket

Tags: linux, sockets, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, coreclr

I followed the [*Publish to a Linux Production Environment*](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html) instruction on the [Microsoft ASP.NET](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/) website. I use CentOS 7.1.

I copied the following line in the project.json file

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://unix:/var/aspnet/HelloMVC/kestrel.sock",
}
```

Then I run the following commands

```
dotnet restore
dotnet run
```

But the kestrel.sock file is not created.

Comment: I believe `"commands"` does not work anymore on RC2 (are you using RC2?). Have you tried `dotnet run --server.urls http://unix:/var/aspnet/HelloMVC/kestrel.sock`? Also make sure your application is set up to accept configuration from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"commands"` element does not work with `dotnet`. [To configure the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365382/41071), you can use either `.UseUrls("http://unix:/var/aspnet/HelloMVC/kestrel.sock")` in your `Main`, or set up command line configuration and then run `dotnet run --server.urls http://unix:/var/aspnet/HelloMVC/kestrel.sock`.