# How to change the port number for Asp.Net core app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, .net-core, port-number

I added the following section in `project.json`.

```
  "commands": {
    "run": "run server.urls=http://localhost:8082",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:8082",
    "weblistener": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:8082"
  },
```

However, it still shows "Now listening on: http://localhost:5000" when run it using `dotnet myapp.dll`?

BTW, will clients from other machine be able to access the service?

Comment: The `"commands"` property is not used by `dotnet` anymore, which explains why it doesn't work.

Comment: [Config port in appsettings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276201/2934730)

Answer (score 80):

Yes this will be accesible from other machines if you bind on any external IP address. For example binding to `http://*:80` . Note that binding to `http://localhost:80` will only bind on 127.0.0.1 interface and therefore will not be accesible from other machines.

Visual Studio is overriding your port.  You can change VS port editing this file `Properties\launchSettings.json` or else set it by code:

```
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:80") // <-----
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

A step by step guide using an external config file is available [here](http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-configure-kestrel-urls-in-aspnet-core-rc2).

Comment: This was essentially what I had to do to get my app to run in Docker... although in that scenario, I did it by setting the environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS to `http://*:80`, and _not_ `http://localhost:80`.  You made my day, thank you!

Comment: And what should I use when my code uses `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)`?

Answer (score 76):

It's working to me.

I use `Asp.net core 2.2` (this way supported in `asp.net core 2.1` and upper version).

add `Kestrel` section in `appsettings.json` file. 
like this:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:4300"
      }
    }
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

and in `Startup.cs`:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
         .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
         .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
         .AddEnvironmentVariables();

      Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

Comment: And `"Url": "http://*:80"` for public facing (don't use for production but useful to for example demo something to a client)

Answer (score 66):

Use simply `dotnet YouApp.dll --urls http://0.0.0.0:80`.

P.S. I don't know why I need to google this everytime and everytime it doesn't show up. So here it is.

Comment: Did not work for me, using dotnet 6. Project still trying to run on the default port (5000 in my case).

Comment: @Sheldonfrith Makes no sense. I use the same command on ASP.Net Core 3.1 and ASP.Net Core 6. They all work.
It's explicitly stated as one of the ways to configure port on ASP.Net Core 7 documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0
You might check whether you have configured ASPNETCORE_URLS which may cause conflicts.

Answer (score 32):

In Asp.net core 2.0 WebApp, if you are using visual studio search **LaunchSettings.json**. I am adding my LaunchSettings.json, you can change port no as u can see.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

In visual studio 2017 we can change the port number from LaunchSetting.json

In Properties-> LaunchSettings.json.

Open LaunchSettings.json and change the Port Number.

[image: Launch]

Change the port Number in json file

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Use following one line of code `.UseUrls("http://*:80")` in `Program.cs`
Thus changing `.UseStartup<Startup>()`
 to
`.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseUrls("http://*:80")`

Answer (score 14):

3 files have to changed `appsettings.json` (see the last section - kestrel ), `launchsettings.json` - applicationurl commented out, and a 2 lines change in `Startup.cs`

Add below code in `appsettings.json` file and port to any as you wish.

```
  },

 "Kestrel": {

   "Endpoints": {

     "Http": {

       "Url": "http://localhost:5003"

     }

   }

 }

 }
```

Modify `Startup.cs` with below lines.

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;`

`services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Kestrel"));`

Answer (score 14):

> will clients from other machine be able to access the service?

add to appsettings.json

```
  "Urls": "http://0.0.0.0:8082",
```

Answer (score 10):

We can use this command to run our host project via Windows Powershell without IIS and visual studio on a separate port. Default of krestel web server is 5001

```
$env:ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://localhost:22742" ; dotnet run
```

Answer (score 9):

Go to your program.cs file add UseUrs method to set your url, make sure you don't use a reserved url or port

```
 public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()

                // params string[] urls
                .UseUrls(urls: "http://localhost:10000")

                .Build();
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Building on @Abdus Salam Azad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386535/114029)...

In Visual Studio 2022 if you right click an ASP.NET Core Web API project for example, you have access to this UI where you can set up ASPNETCORE variables like this:

[image]

There you can enter a custom URL:port for `ASPNETCORE_URLS` like this:

[image]

https://localhost:44777

Answer (score 6):

All the other answer accounts only for `http` URLs. If the URL is `https`, then do as follows,

1. Open `launchsettings.json` under Properties of the API project.

   [image]
2. Change the `sslPort` under `iisSettings -> iisExpress`

A sample `launchsettings.json` will look as follows

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:12345",
      "sslPort": 98765 <== Change_This
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works in ASP.Net Core 6.0. Inside Program.cs have this:

```c#
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://*:80", "https://*.443");
}
```

I find it is useful to wrap it in a conditional statement when publishing to production, but this isn't necessary.

This works running from a Kestrel server on Mac OS 12.

Answer (score 3):

in appsetting.json

{
"DebugMode": false,
"Urls": "http://localhost:8082"
}

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net core 6
`app.Run("https://*:25565");`
or in my case for deploying on heroku
`app.Run("https://*:"+Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"));`

Answer (score 1):

you can also code like this

```
        IConfiguration config  = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build(); 
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
         .UseConfiguration(config)
         .UseKestrel()
         .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) 
         .UseStartup<Startup>()
         .Build();
```

and set up your application by command line :dotnet run --server.urls http://*:5555

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's because I am not using Core yet. My project didn't have a LaunchSettings.json file but that did prompt me to look in the project properties. I found it under the Web tab and simply changed the project url:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run on a specific port 60535 while developing locally but want to run app on port 80 in stage/prod environment servers, this does it.

Add to environmentVariables section in launchSettings.json

```
"ASPNETCORE_DEVELOPER_OVERRIDES": "Developer-Overrides",
```

and then modify Program.cs to

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        var devOverride = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_DEVELOPER_OVERRIDES");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(devOverride))
                        {
                            options.ListenLocalhost(60535);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            options.ListenAnyIP(80);
                        }
                    })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseNLog();                   
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a Kubernetes deployment after upgrading to .NET 6. The solution was simply to add the following environment variable to the deployment:

```
- name: Kestrel__Endpoints__Http__Url
  value: http://0.0.0.0:80
```

This will work anywhere else where you can use an environment variable

Answer (score 1):

Core 6.0 -->
Without any JSON setting changes we do some thing like this..
I also commented some code bcoz I don't have certificate. we can run it any port.

```
 builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
            {
               // serverOptions.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 5003);
                serverOptions.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 8086, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps();
              //listenOptions.UseHttps("testCert.pfx", "testPassword");
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

in your hosting.json 
replace`"Url": "http://localhost:80"` by`"Url": "http://*:80"` and you will be able now access to your application by `http://your_local_machine_ip:80`  for example `http://192.168.1.4:80`

Answer (score 0):

I created my project using Visual Studio 2022, so in Project/Properties/launchSettings.json there are two parts for this topic:
1- for lunching in IISExpress :

```
"iisSettings": {
..
"iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:31520",
  "sslPort": 44346
}
```

},

2- for lunching through IDE:

```
"profiles": {
"MaxTemplate.API": {
  ...
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7141;http://localhost:5141",
  ...
  }
},
```

For example you can change the port 7141 to 5050 and run the project again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to add this as a comment, but I want to add that the `WebHost.UseUrls()` in `.net core 6` can be set using a combination of `IPAddress` and `IPEndPoint` in file `Program.cs`

```
if (!builder.Environment.IsDevelopment()) // app in release
{
               // listen to any ip on port 80 for http
    IPEndPoint ipEndPointHttp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 80),
           
               // listen to any ip on port 443 for https
               ipEndPointHttps = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 443);

    builder.WebHost.UseUrls($"http://{ipEndPointHttp}",
                            $"https://{ipEndPointHttps}");

    // enforce ssl when in release
    builder.Services.AddHsts(options =>
    {
        options.Preload = true;
        options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
        options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(3); // a commonly used value is one year.
    });

    // redirect to specific https port
    builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PermanentRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = ipEndPointHttps.Port;
    });
}
else // app in debug
{
               // listen to localhost on port 8081 for http
    IPEndPoint ipEndPointHttp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8081),

               // listen to localhost on port 5001 for https
               ipEndPointHttps = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001);

    builder.WebHost.UseUrls($"http://{ipEndPointHttp}",
                            $"https://{ipEndPointHttps}");

    // redirect to specific https port
    builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = ipEndPointHttps.Port;
    });
}

... // rest of configuration

app.UseHttpsRedirection(); // set redirection to https if url is in http

....
```

Also note that using these values `new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 80)`, `*:80`, `::80` are all equivalent, but I prefer IPEndPoint since it is more verbose

If a custom ip address (ex: `192.168.1.200`) is needed other than `IPAddress.Any` or `IPAddress.Loopback`, a new address can be set using `IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.200")`

Answer (score 0):

go to launchsettings.json and change all the ports you can see there, including the ones in the IIS section

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the new .NET versions without the Startup.cs file you can add line

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:5010", "https://localhost:5011");
```

after the line

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

like so

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:5010", "https://localhost:5011");
```

and it will change the ports to 5010 and 5011 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me in March 2024, running net8.0 and a minimal webAPI with top-level statements:

At the top of your `Program.cs` you'll see a line of code something like:

`var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`

Place the following code after that:

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
{
    // 5270 is the port number
    serverOptions.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, 5270);
});
```

This started the app on 127.0.0.1:5270.

This allowed me to set up nginx running on Linux to point to this app.