# How to change the default port in asp.net Core 3 or Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0, self-host-webapi

when I am in debug, to change the default port, I modify the launchSettings.json file, and change the port

```
"WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://*:8081;http://*:8080"
    }
```

but if I publish the application in a folder (selfHost) and launch the executable, it always listens on port 5000
Someone knows how to change the default port in production.
I tried changing it in the program.cs with **UseUrls** but not working

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                }).UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseUrls("http://*:8080","https://*:8081");
                })
            .UseSerilog();
```

Comment: these all say localhost.  did you also use the domain name of production when you put it in production?

Comment: the application is selfhosted, that example is in debug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the port number for Asp.Net core app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755516/how-to-change-the-port-number-for-asp-net-core-app)

Comment: the domain name does not have to do if it is self hosted.  If it is on a server then it can't be on localhost.  localhost is only for local machines.   check the question you are a duplicate of ... it is explained well there.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I finally got it
before

```
   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
```

add

```
 webBuilder.UseUrls("https://*:8081", "http://*:8080");
```

this is the code

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                }).UseWindowsService()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseUrls("https://*:8081", "http://*:8080");
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
            .UseSerilog();
}
```

I hope it can be useful to someone else.
thank you

Comment: FYI, you can also set an environment variable, so that the values aren't hardcoded into your app. `ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://*:8081;http://*:8080` should do it.

Answer (score 10):

### Use command line arguments

dotnet run --urls "http://localhost:5100;https://localhost:5101"

- OR -

dotnet /Product/Full/Path/Product.dll --urls "http://localhost:5100;https://localhost:5101"

Answer (score 7):

Yoy can simple changing the port via changing the **LaunchSettings.json.**

you can find by **Properties-> LaunchSettings.json.**

[image]

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
  "iisExpress": {
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:8080",
  "sslPort": 96085<== Change_This as you wish
  }
},
```