# .NET CORE app to start on port 80 instead on port 5000

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to run a .net core app inside of the docker container. The docker image that I'm using to run a container is `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1`.

I need to SDK image because I'm trying to build and run the app inside of the same container.

So, I need help with starting the app on port 80 inside of the container. I have tried setting `ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+80` but the app still runs on port 5000.

Comment: you appsetting.json  or  .csproj file has 5000 port

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the port number for Asp.Net core app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755516/how-to-change-the-port-number-for-asp-net-core-app)

Comment: `http://+80` is obviously invalid. Read the documentation carefully, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#server-urls