# ASP.NET Core redirect http to https but I don't want to do it in localhost also I use a different port

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ssl, redirect

In ,net core 2.1, I want to redirect from http to https.

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
   {
    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
    options.HttpsPort = 5001;
    });
```

However in localhost I don't use https, I just use http. Also I use a different port.

```
"MyProject": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:50642",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
```

It doesn't work in localhost unless I change the port to 5001 in `launchSettings.json`. How to make it working?

Comment: Maybe this resolve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755516/how-to-change-the-port-number-for-asp-net-core-app

Comment: There are duplicates about this already but why not use HTTPS in localhost too? If you don't you'll have to wait until production to find about redirection errors. Any certificate problems you may have can be fixed by trusting the development certificate created by ASP.NET Core or using a valid certificate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I can use https in localhost but I just don't want to create ssl certification for loalhost.

Comment: Are you on Linux or Mac? There's an OpenSSL bug that requires extra attributes from self-signed certificates that was fixed this July and obviously hasn't made it to all distributions yet. There are guides that show how to overcome this as well

Comment: @Hello why? In Windows it works out of the box, the certificate is produced by .NE Core itself, you don't have to do anything. Troubleshooting HTTPS issues *after* deployment is a lot harder

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, it runs for https in Windows but it shows insecure before the url bar. It seems that I have to create a localhost ssl certification. I just want to save some time.

Comment: All you need to do is trust that certificate, from that very icon. Not that it affects anything - only you see that local site. There's nothing to fix. You're *losing* time right now trying to juggle with the settings. When you deploy your project you'll install a different certificate

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I agree with that. Since it is localhost, the icon does't impact anything. Maybe I just use 5001 is fine. But let me just keep the question open to see if any other bizarre thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the port as

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
```

When you click F5 to debug, Visual Studio 2017 will ask you to install a cert for you automatically. You don't have to manually to do it.

Answer (score 3):

if you don't want to redirect http > https in development, then in your `Configure` method use an if around `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`

```
if (appSettings.HttpsPort.HasValue)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
}
```