# asp.net core's default application using docker starts with two launch urls

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a basic Asp.net core 2.0 web application in the following way:

New Application => ASP.Net Core Web Application => Web Application => 
 (MVC) => Change Authentication => Individual User Accounts (With docker enabled)

Debugging this will give you this:

[image]

This will obviously give you a 404, if you get rid of `https://localhost:44360/` then the application is debugging there. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40552670/8020051), but this didn't work for me.

I created a `hosting.json` as the answer suggested:

```
{
  "server": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel",
  "server.urls": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

I added this to the `Configure()` method in startup:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("/app/hosting.json", optional: false)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
            .Build();
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
host.Run();
```

This didn't fix my startup issue. What am I doing wrong or what do i need to do to fix this debug issue?

Answer (score 4):

I was seeing the same issue after creating a new project and installing Docker for Windows with Visual Studio Community 2017.

It appears that the docker-compose Property Pages had a bad Service URL property, which in my case was generated as:  `http://localhost:{ServicePort}/https://localhost:44339/`

To fix the issue:

- Right-click the `docker-compose` project
- Select `Properties`
- Replace `Service URL` with: `http://localhost:{ServicePort}`

Comment: Same here - and this is Visual Studio 2019 with all updates applied running a .NET 5 ASP.NET Core Web App for Razor. Come on Microsoft; fix this issue :-)