# Asp.Net Core application only listening to port 5000 on Ubuntu

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I'm new to .Net Core. I have hosted my .Net core application in Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and mentioned the port needs to run in the service file.

```
[Unit]
Description=My Web Application

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myapp/idp/ums
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/myapp/idp/ums/myapp.dll --urls=http://localhost:6006
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=my-app-web
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But it doesn't use the provided URL and always listening on port 5000.

[image]

I haven't mentioned port number 5000 anywhere in my application (not mentioned in launchSettings.json, or UserUrls in Program.cs).

I do have some other .Net core application in the same server and listens on the port provided in the service file.

Here are my application's Program.cs and startup method,

**Porgram.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

**Startup.cs**

https://gist.github.com/Karthikeyan-tv/d2f93bb8d7d20ddc9dfbc1adac450c52

Is there any way to find out why the app is only listening on port 5000?

Comment: 5000 is the default port . This might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on

Comment: what version of .net core? Not sure if this will work for you, but I've been using ASPNETCORE_URLS since 2.x.  Remove the `--urls` parameter passed to dotnet, and add the following line to the `[SERVICE]` section of the service file: `Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:6006`

Answer (score 0):

Passing `--urls` never worked for me, probably because systemd needs this string to be escaped via `systemd-escape` first

However passing as an env-variable worked

`Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:6006`

P.S. MS docs actually mention escaping here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=linux-ubuntu#create-the-service-file-1