# How to host a blazor application?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to run a blazor application that I have made, and I would like to publish for people who are not on my computer. I have changed the launchsettings.json to the following

```
 "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000;https://192.168.50.15:16000;",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

As I understand it I should be able to connect to this web page on my phone on the same network. However, when I go to 192.168.50.15:16000 on my phone I get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in google chrome. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled incoming TCP-traffic to port 16000 in the firewall on the computer that hosts the app?

Comment: Yep, both incoming and out going

Comment: And what does https://192.168.50.15:16000 show on (the same | another) PC ?

Comment: You didn't post the outer Json for this and did not specify how you run this, Did the Console window say `"Now listening on https://192.168.50.15:16000"` ?

Comment: Did you use publish on your application? If so you should look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on to make sure it is hosted on the correct port

Comment: The console did output listening on https://192.168.50.15:16000 and the application is not published. On my pc where it is hosted it shows the blazor page. On all other devices it give ERR_RESPONSE_EMPTY

Comment: I would expect problems with accepting the localhost certificate. Not sure if that could show up as RESPONSE_EMPTY. You may try `http://` (no `s`), just for luck.

Comment: Yeah, on HTTPS it doesnt pull any response, and with HTTP it just returns a blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hosting my blazor application, my guess is it did have something to do with local host's certificate not being accepted. For anyone who is interested, [this](https://www.jeremymorgan.com/blog/linux/blazor-in-linux/) tutorial was a great help to do that.