# .NET Core self-contained deployment: HOWTO change the PORT for ASP.NET Core Web API?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, port, publish

I am deploying a simple ASP.NET Core 6 Web API via Microsoft's self-contained deployment method. When running the EXE, it always binds to port 5000/5001 - how does one change that port to something else?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify the port an ASP.NET Core application is hosted on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365277/how-to-specify-the-port-an-asp-net-core-application-is-hosted-on)