# How can I view .net core 2 sites served from vs code from a remote machine?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm playing with vs code and a new asp.net core 2 webapi project.
When I debug it or run it without debugging I can access the site from the same machine using `http://localhost:5000` but I can't work out (and haven't found anything for the new .net core 2 way of doing things) to allow me to change the listening url to something like `http://0.0.0.0:5000` or even `http://*:5000` so I can access the dev site from another machine on the network to test with IE (it's running on a Mac).

I have found plenty of examples for .net core <2 that show editing the `Program.cs` file and adding a host config but that file has changed now (simplified) and I can't find or work out a way to apply the same changes to the new layout.

As well as other questions and solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36101184/769294) that modify a `hosting.json` or `project.json` which both appear from my reasearch to have been removed or more replaced with the `.csproj` file. And again I have been unable to work out or find information on how to implement the same changes in the new `.csproj` file.

So could someone please point me in the right direction. I expected changing the host/listening url to be a LOT easier than this so I'm sure I am missing something obvious.

Comment: I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39733403/2698119, but I couldn't make it work. Maybe it will work for you though.

Comment: Thanks @Métoule but that is again the same code for the old .net Code 1.# from what I understand that has changed for core 2.# when the program.cs changed. See the section half way down called: "Update Main method in Program.cs" in this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/
You can see the change from what that answer shows to what is there now. :(

Comment: The `CreateDefaultBuilder` method is meant to simplify the boilerplate code, but underneath, it looks to be identical to 1.x : https://github.com/aspnet/MetaPackages/blob/7511a4da7f1d1d9651d19801aadea77f557e0b11/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore/WebHost.cs#L148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update:

I have just come across the Environment variables which seem a FAR better place to set this, also this is how I would have done it in VS 2017.

In JetBrains Rider they are under the build configs (`Run` dropdown then `Edit Configurations...`).

[image: Run - Edit Configurations]

Under this window you can edit your build configurations. Find the one you use (I only have one currently but you might have a dev, staging etc...) and then find the `Environment variables:` (green) and click the button on the right (blue).

[image: Run/Debug Configurations]

In the new window you can change the `ASPNETCORE_URLS` to what ever you require. For me I set it to `http://*:5000` which causes it to pick up any incoming requests. For example `localhost:5000` or `192.168.0.10:5000`. I then pointed my `dev.somedomain.com` to `192.168.0.10:5000` and I can use https though NGINX to test on my dev site running on my Mac.

[image]

This also allows for easily changing it on a PC my PC basis by not checking in the JetBrains Rider settings.

---

## Original Answer:

I have finally found the answer to this and @Métoule was right in the comment. I just didn't understand what it meant until now.

Basically the changes in the `Program.cs` in ASP.NET CORE 2.0 is just a way to hide away the stuff that will always be the same.
Instead of calling all these (like you needed to in Core 1):

```cs
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseApplicationInsights()
.Build();
```

You're just calling the ones you're likely to want to change:

```cs
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();
```

SO you can still add `UseUrls()` as before just put it before the `.Build`();` like this:

```cs
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseUrls("http://192.168.2.10:5000")
.Build();
```

SO to change the Url of a brand new ASP.NET CORE 2 project I changed the `Program` class in the `Program.cs` file from:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

To:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls("http://192.168.2.22:5000")
            .Build();
}
```

Only adding the 3rd from last line: `.UseUrls("http://192.168.2.22:5000")`
As long as there are no firewalls in the way I can now access the above url from another machine on the network and see my dev site! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is my `program.cs` class in .NET Core 2.0 :

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Note the `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")` that accept any incoming requests from port `5000`. This is only used when you **publish** your application (right click on the projet, publish...).

When you run your application **from** VS 2017 (for exemple), VS takes the settings under `Properties/launchSettings.json`. You can edit this file anytime.

Hope this will help someone else because I wasted too much time on this!

Comment: I'm not sure what this is adding to my answer?

Comment: Mainly the possibility of using directly `.UseUrls("http://*:5000")` in `program.cs`  instead of adding `http://*:5000` in the environment variable ASPNETCORE_URLS.

Comment: So like my original answer? ;) Well bar replacing the IP with wildcard as covered in the newer part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late to the conversation, but if you are still trying to get this to work with VS Code, you are able to set ENVIRONMENT variables directly in your VS Code launch.json.

```
    {
// Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
// Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
// For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/vscode-env.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
                "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://*:5000"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```